# Best (pythonic) way to interrupt and cancel a function call in progress?

Tags: python, multithreading

I want a function `foo()` to do a number of things in one thread, with waiting periods during which it periodically checks if another thread (the main script) has set a `please_stop` variable to `True`, in which case I want `foo()` to immediately return a value (e.g., `False`).

My initial attempt looks like this:

```
import time

please_stop = False

def wait( n ) :
    '''
    Wait n seconds and return True, unless some other process
    sets please_stop to True (and then return False).
    '''
    global please_stop
    for t in range (n) :
        if please_stop :
            please_stop = False
            return False
        else :
            print t
            time.sleep(1)
    return True

def foo() :
    '''
    Do a number of things, with wait() calls in between.
    '''
    global please_stop
    print 'doing first thing'
    if not wait( 5 ) : return False
    print 'doing second thing'
    if not wait( 5 ) : return False
    print 'doing third thing'
    return True

foo()
```

It works as it should, but I find the `if not wait( 5 ) : return False` expressions very clunky. What would be the simplest / most elegant way to achieve this behavior, possibly allowing the use of a simple `wait( 5 )` expression instead? Am I re-inventing the wheel, would something like interrupts do a better job here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replace the whole 'wait' thing with multiprocessing.Event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can simplify the implementation of `wait` by using a [`threading.Event`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects) instead of a global variable:

```
import time
import threading


def wait(event, timeout):
    if event.wait(timeout):
        event.clear()
        return False
    else:
        return True

def foo(event):
    '''
    Do a number of things, with wait() calls in between.
    '''
    print 'doing first thing'
    if not wait(event, 5): return False
    print 'doing second thing'
    if not wait(event, 5): return False
    print 'doing third thing'
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event = threading.Event()
    t = threading.Thread(target=foo, args=(event,))
    t.start()
    time.sleep(6)
    event.set()
```

Output:

```
doing first thing
doing second thing
```

But you're still using the `if not wait(5) : return False` pattern. To get rid of that, you'd need to throw an exception when the `Event` is set. You probably don't want the exception to escape from `foo`, though, so you need to either use a `try`/`except` block around the `foo` body, or use a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager):

```
import time
import threading
from contextlib import contextmanager

class Interrupt(Exception): pass

def wait(event, timeout):
    if event.wait(timeout):
        event.clear()
        raise Interrupt()
    else:
        return True

@contextmanager
def interruptible():
    try:
        yield
    except Interrupt:
        pass

def foo(event):
    '''
    Do a number of things, with wait() calls in between.
    '''
    with interruptible():
        print 'doing first thing'
        wait(event, 5)
        print 'doing second thing'
        wait(event, 5)
        print 'doing third thing'
        return True
    return False  # This will only be reached the main thread interrupts foo
```

This will behave exactly the same as the previous example, the only difference is instead of returning `False` to end `foo`, we raise an exception, which gets caught by the context manager, but causes us to skip the rest of the code inside of the context.